# Не могу понять почему выдает ошибку. Необходимо сделать так, чтобы при написании всего чего угодно кроме цифр выводило сообщение попробуйте еще раз

Tags: python, исключения, try

```
def numbers():

    num1 = int(input('Введите число №1: '))
    num2 = int(input('Введите число №2: '))
    print(num1 + num2)
    try:
        num1 = str(input('Введите число №1: '))
        num2 = str(input('Введите число №2: '))
    except ValueError:
        print('Вы ввели текст вместо чисел! Попробуйте снова.')
    else:
        num1 = int(input('Введите число №1: '))
        num2 = int(input('Введите число №2: '))
        print(num1 + num2)

numbers()
```

Comment: ну так прочитай ошибку и поймешь

Comment: Спасибо за такой совет , но ошибка была прочитана. От этого нечего не изменилось. Я думал, что этот сервис нужен для помощи тем, кто не может, что-то решить

Comment: ну так понятно, что от чтения ошибки ошибка не исправится. Ошибка выводится для того, чтобы программист понял в чем проблема и исправил ее, изменив код. Сервис нужен для помощи тем, кто не может что-то решить, верно. Но чтобы что-то решить нужно хотя бы начать решать. Кроме того, по ссылке в плашке над вопросом есть решение.